# WKWebview obscures toolbar

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I have searched around for a couple of nights now and haven't been able to find a solution to this problem.

I am trying to load a web view and also have a toolbar at the bottom.

code:

```
class WebAppViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.frame.size = webView.scrollView.contentSize
    view = webView


    let defaults = `UserDefaults`.standard
    let email = defaults.object(forKey: "email") as? String
    let password = defaults.object(forKey: "password") as? String

    let myURL = URL(string:"https://google.com")
    var request = URLRequest(url: myURL!)

    webView.load(request)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I have found that if I remove this line:

```
view = webView
```

Then I get an empty view with the toolbar at the bottom. When I add that line back in, the website that I'm loading takes over the entire view.

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

UPDATE

As per answer I have split the work over the two functions:

```
class WebAppViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        let defaults = `UserDefaults`.standard
        let email = defaults.object(forKey: "email") as? String
        let password = defaults.object(forKey: "password") as? String

        let myURL = URL(string:"https://google.com")
        var request = URLRequest(url: myURL!)

        webView.load(request)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    }

}
```

However I am still seeing the web view across the entire view.

Comment: For context, someone answered and advised me to split the code into 2 functions. I did this and then the answer was downvoted and deleted (not by me, obviously).

Comment: how are you creating your toolbar?

Comment: Thanks @Spads - I've created it in interface builder. You can see the toolbar when i remove the line "view = webView" - it is there when i build and run the app. But it isn't there when I include that line. In Interface builder I have all the constraints as they should be with regards to making sure everything fits on the screen as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I’m guessing with your loadView() function, specifically the line view=webView you are completely replacing your view hierarchy and losing your toolbar. Get rid of the function loadView(). At the bottom of the viewDidLoad() add the following.

```
view.insertSubview(webView, belowSubview:toolbarView)
```